# When is it appropriate to post WordPress-related questions on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, tags, scope

When is it appropriate to post WordPress-related questions on Stack Overflow as opposed to wordpress.stackexchange.com?

The Stack Overflow [wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress) tag wiki states:

> WordPress is an open source content management system running on PHP and MySQL, and often used as a blog engine. WordPress questions about programming and administration are best asked on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/.

But what types of question should fall into this category? Isn't the primary function of Stack Overflow for asking programming related questions?

We often see this type of question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24640588/paginating-wordpress-posts-category-page appear on Stack Overflow where one might argue that the OP is abusing the WordPress tag in order to gain a larger audience than they may other wise have done on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/.

However, in the end it may not have been of much benefit to the OP, as useful responses will only be provided by Stack Overflow members with reasonable knowledge of the WordPress API.

Comment: When they're programming-related.  That the Tag Wiki recommends WordPress Answers for programming questions doesn't necessarily make them off-topic here.

Comment: but the wordpress tag itself says that questions about programming and administration are best asked on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The third paragraph of the Tag Wiki says: *"This tag is for programming-specific questions related to WordPress, especially those that involve a mix of languages and technologies (PHP, MySQL, CSS, JavaScript/jQuery and others). Questions about plugin and theme development, WordPress administration, management best practices and server configuration are best asked on Stack Exchange WordPress Development."*  That's pretty good advice.

Comment: @RobertHarvey so what you're saying is, programming related WordPress questions are *on-topic* here, but it's even better if you ask them over at [wordpress.se]?

Comment: Why aren't you guys reading the text?  It says to prefer Stack Overflow if your WordPress programming questions involve multiple technologies, but prefer WordPress Answers if you're writing plugin or theme code.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, that's not really what it says, though. It's just "*especially* those that involve a mix of language". If you're programming something that doesn't necessarily involve such a mix, it's still ambiguous.

Comment: @Bruno: Then use your best judgement.

Comment: @andrew +1 I stopped flagging plugin-related questions for migration because it seems that there's no consensus on this

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> When is it appropriate to post Wordpress related questions on Stack Overflow as opposed to wordpress.stackexchange.com?

It is appropriate to post a WordPress question whenever it is related to a specific programming problem you are facing when using wordpress, just like Robert Harvey said in the comments.

Here are a few examples of on topic questions:

- How do I do this thing in PHP in the posts page? - or more genetally, PHP questions where you just happen to use WordPress.
- Adding this JavaScript AJAX thing in the admin panel always gives null with PHP5.5 - That is, JavaScript and PHP questions where you just happen to use WordPress
- JavaScript behavior on document load with `postMessage` - general JS questions where you just happen to use WordPress and add the tag to give more context to the question
- Why does WordPress plugin PHP with `get_posts` gives partial posts? - PHP questions that related to the wordpress API, yes - just like add other programming APIs these are fine.

Here are some off topic ones:

- How do I recover my password for WordPress.com? - About a third party provider and not programming.
- How do I configure plugins in WordPress? - Not programming related, but administration related.
- How do I create users in WordPress? - Same thing.
- What is a cool plugin that does Foo? - Off topic for two whole reasons, because it's a third party library request and because it's not programming related.
- How do I add comments to wordpress? - Too broad as a programming questions, off topic as a WP administration one.
- Should I use WordPress? - Off topic, opinionated and not programming related.

So basically - **You can ask WordPress questions when they're specific programming related questions** that are within the scope of "on topic" in the help center.